# Node.js: xlsx with axios - how to store data as XML?

Tags: node.js, axios

When i try to make a get request with Axios on a .xslx file, i get some special characters (maybe it's binary? I don't know) on my console.

**it looks like this:**

```
�V�?x�(~�O!�OXȽGG��x��ӫ��+j��&����Z�֗_��
                                       �v�z��˦�5b?i3�E�k�f{���2�⠌>�%���W

                                                                        D�DNb���)�B0�d����j�n����m-E_>�*w�@<�=�=Ld=F�-�ɉ`�Ⱦ�y:��]�qÃra:�N�,Τ�f�Xk��`�/RW�-��mI��Ȋ!ɠ����wI���fR!���C��@l�6��/���
                                               Œ�鐾���R���+C%P�54T`Q���݉�O}׬6����d�ת���k��!gU-d!��x�yyi�HN�c�� �׷"�'ы$%�0a�?w4�P���Ⱥ�eA��NJS|j�·kJl;�8����]��t�W3��qz��O�
                                                       ߔ!xl�+�Q�z���Qi��4=1\]�;��gT^���Zg�^��U��!|n1�qc��suX11�Uuj��ThO:7>0���!����.
                   �<���[i�*��l���
                                  J%.�>�ٹZ��=���.l�`|jv.��geb���ecq���>C�*�
�3N�?�                                                                    �&����r��t���2�إ�
      2C�V�M�R�R�<[zRO�0߬����f�  �����w�(�����z���{�8�P�����Ϧ�V�qn�vqK
                                                                     '1���i��f)k��D*QmQ�B�Z��ػ�&����O�����3����&�OdsEa�FP��:e_⺽��k��x��'�(�_��<���{��¬���8�������%OYu˃�<��҆���Z�_��l�y�F�:�:]�|��Qb�]d>��+ϴ�Z10O��*ݐ'�}���3g�R.��yth�˘��d��Tܼ)�!�U�ӀQ[���KsX�#)�O+��zĭZ���9l�k�M��h�Xݯ�=���$��C���)�#w]�J�r�������;5
��Gt������������P5¯߳{�Y�[����$�.��^N����ܰ~�̲�]�b��o���v�xhs�ɼN��v��h����1}��P'���Ez>ᣍiԯ�fq�����ޗ�r7���uB�n�����d�=�vTUs�{�%XB�����M�i��{�\J���+���F�JH
                                  �1�<ב0[�ټ�{��_��b�t��H�i�E�ols���%I���k���d1�>
                                                                                ��-xdn;�1S�cl������]m0
                                                                                                      ���       �޾�!�v/�e�:갮����x��3�h�A
                        �B�U$rW��-)��Z�C�K�}l5O����C�7E׼��G�]e猆�߲Hv��_t-�g�)
                                                                            ���o�?��G�J,Z�7�o�ٗ�qN 
                                                                                                  ��v��&eb��B��KT���&���^��K�<{��֦�xмW�.4��
<��<" �o��Pl�,N`Mn]�?d[rv��n&;Y>�5p��Y Y���Jr�*M�$����E�R���M���?��7wby��       � p��   � � �/��P!S���� xl/calcChain.xmlt�݊�0��}�0�kڪ��4텬O�>@HǶ���ѷw`Q�5��㜜�i��5�!N�I(�0t�����[`1)�+�J�`���X4Z��5�(aLi��<���K?�#r���D�0�8T}�5�*���IB���P�}�D���R�e����U�s�n�2W��E�\���?s~?b{��P!�����docProps/core.xml �(�|�]o� ��'�? ��
                                                                                        p>� Ǒ�)��*U��V�#�&a3`[�?�>hg��(F`�S�n�[��
�BV��YX���>~(e˥�p�]
                   >(�l�]�]�-'$�FIa�q�1}�-i��)�@rJg�@JDA:`֞�x@*yF��|��$Ѐ#F^��    ��˅��xhS�!�%[���~       �,���������3�|�����i�m%W��\z����n4��4#xtޮ�AW��SI.tݦ�.ͿѠn�h@��B�j�������WB�{m���)+2F3:���s>�/��;�R�~�c���T��9]�Ʒ���x�MȢf9�Nx�+������H����8�\O���������PK!`�z��
                                   [Content_Types].xmlPK!�U0#�L
                                                               �_rels/.relsPK!�i�W
```

I have tried some different responseType settings, but it gives me the same output. I have also tried to change the responseEncoding, but still no change in the output.

This is my axios call - all plain and simple. As i said, i have tried with responseType settings and responseEncoding... (the URL is private thats why it just says link.xlsx).

```
app.get("/pep", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const pepList = await axios({
      url:
        "link.xlsx?la=da"
    });
    console.log(pepList.data);
```

Do you know how to get some data from this that i can use? I need to be able to get the xlsx data to XML data?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest parsing the downloaded .xlsx file using the [xlsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx) module, this allows you to convert worksheets to json. This can then be converted to xml using [jsontoxml](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsontoxml).

Using an example online .xlsx file:

```
const axios = require("axios");
const XLSX = require("xlsx");
const jsontoxml = require("jsontoxml");

async function testAxiosXlsx(url) {
    const options = { 
        url,
        responseType: "arraybuffer"
    }
    let axiosResponse = await axios(options);
    const workbook = XLSX.read(axiosResponse.data);

    let worksheets = workbook.SheetNames.map(sheetName => {
        return { sheetName, data: XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sheetName]) };
    });

    console.log("json:\n", JSON.stringify(worksheets), "\n\n");
    console.log("xml:\n", jsontoxml(worksheets, {}));
}

testAxiosXlsx("https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/file_example_XLSX_10.xlsx");
```

This will log the .xlsx file as xml data, it'll look something like this:

```
<sheetName>Sheet1</sheetName>
<data>
    <0>1</0>
    <First Name>Dulce</First Name>
    <Last Name>Abril</Last Name>
    <Gender>Female</Gender>
    <Country>United States</Country>
    <Age>32</Age>
    <Date>15/10/2017</Date>
    <Id>1562</Id>
</data>
```

Comment: Thanks! This really helped me 

Comment: Note that the key thing that made this work is using responseType: "arraybuffer" in the axios options.